# remove Union from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I have query to get category and subcategories of same category. I used below query:

```
    Select Id from category where name like '%events%' and deleted = 0 and published = 1
UNION
SELECT Id from category where parentcategoryid = (Select id from category where name like '%events%' and deleted = 0 and published = 1)
```

I do not want to use UNION, want to use Join only. But not getting how i can achieve. Below is the table structure. Please help me. thanks in Advance

[image: Category Table]

Comment: You can simply use OR: `SELECT Id FROM category WHERE (... first condition ...) OR (... second condition ...)`

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might solve your problem:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int, name varchar(20), parentcatid varchar(200))
insert into @t values(23,'Christmas', 34)
                        ,(29,'Birthday', 34)
                        ,(31,'New year', 34)
                        ,(34,'Events', 0)
                        ,(35,'gfrhrt', 0)
                        
;WITH cte AS(
  Select Id from @t
  where name like '%events%' --and deleted = 0 and published = 1
),
cte2 AS (
SELECT a.id AS tId, cpa.id, cId2.id AS idPa
  from @t a
  LEFT JOIN cte AS cId ON cId.Id = a.Id
  FULL OUTER JOIN @t AS cPa ON cPa.parentcatid = cId.Id
  LEFT JOIN cte cId2 ON cId2.id = cPa.id
  WHERE cId.Id IS NOT NULL OR cPa.Id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id
  FROM cte2
  WHERE tId IS NOT NULL
    OR id = idPa
```

The idea is to get all required IDs within the cte and then get all categories, where either ID oder ParentID match the IDs from the cte. However, depending on the size of your table, you might want to add further filters to the cte.

Comment: How you will get all id within the cte. you will get only one id due to filter condition in cte

Comment: In cte you selected only one column that is id. then  how we will use "cPa.parentcategoryid". If i'm wrong pls assist me.

Comment: Concerning your second question, I just modified the answer and added the parentcategory. Concerning your first question: you will get all ID's matching your criteria in the first select before the union and with this result you perform the second left join

Comment: Your query only giving id = 34.create table #table (id int, name varchar(20), parentcatid varchar(200))

insert  into #table values(23,'Christmas', 34) ,(29,'Birthday', 34),(31,'New year', 34),(34,'Events', 0),(35,'gfrhrt', 0)

WITH cte AS(
Select Id, parentcatid 
from #table
where name like '%events%' --and deleted = 0 and published = 1
)
SELECT a.id 
from #table  a
LEFT JOIN cte AS cId ON cId.Id = a.Id
LEFT JOIN cte AS cPa ON cPa.parentcatid = cId.Id
WHERE cId.Id IS NOT NULL
OR cPa.Id IS NOT NULL

Comment: I modified the answer once more. I added another cte to take care of the problem